# Store current timestamp in parquet using ParquetWriter

Tags: timestamp, parquet, current-time

I am using following method to write data in parquet file :

```
static void toParquet() {
        String schema = "message spark_schema {\n  optional binary stringField (UTF8);\n  optional INT96  createdAt;\n}";
        MessageType readSchema = MessageTypeParser.parseMessageType(schema);
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        GroupWriteSupport.setSchema(readSchema, configuration);
        SimpleGroupFactory sfg = new SimpleGroupFactory(readSchema);
        Path file = new Path("/home/user/data-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".parquet");
        try {
            ParquetWriter<Group> writer = new ParquetWriter<Group>(file, new GroupWriteSupport(), CompressionCodecName.UNCOMPRESSED, 1024, 1024, 512,
                    true, false, ParquetProperties.WriterVersion.PARQUET_1_0, configuration);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
                writer.write(sfg.newGroup().append("stringField", "abc").append("createdAt", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())));

            }
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But it gives me following exception :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fixed Binary size 13 does not
>   match field type length 12    at
>   org.apache.parquet.column.values.plain.FixedLenByteArrayPlainValuesWriter.writeBytes(FixedLenByteArrayPlainValuesWriter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.DictionaryValuesWriter$PlainFixedLenArrayDictionaryValuesWriter.createDictionaryPage(DictionaryValuesWriter.java:324)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.column.values.fallback.FallbackValuesWriter.createDictionaryPage(FallbackValuesWriter.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterV1.flush(ColumnWriterV1.java:242)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriteStoreV1.flush(ColumnWriteStoreV1.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.flushRowGroupToStore(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.checkBlockSizeReached(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.write(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter.write(ParquetWriter.java:288)
>     at com.app.test.SimpleParquet.toParquet(SimpleParquet.java:498)     at
>   com.app.test.SimpleParquet.main(SimpleParquet.java:63)

As System.currentTimeMillis() gives 13 byte value and epoc time is of 10 byte how to provide int96 value for current timestamp which is a fixed length 12 byte array.

I found some threads in which they say that the timestamp is combination of julian day and time in nanosecs, how can i convert current timestamp into this format?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes, i have posted the answer - plz check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following piece of code worked for me in which i have calculated NanoTime and then called toBinary function on it.

```
public static NanoTime getNanoTime(String time) {
        Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(time);
        Calendar calendar = getCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(ts);
        JDateTime jDateTime = new JDateTime(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        int days = jDateTime.getJulianDayNumber();
        long hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        long minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        long second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        long nanos = ts.getNanos();
        long nanosOfDay = nanos + NANOS_PER_SECOND * second + NANOS_PER_SECOND * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE * minute + NANOS_PER_SECOND * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE
                * MINUTES_PER_HOUR * hour;
        return new NanoTime(days, nanosOfDay);
    }
```

While writing in parquet used above method -

```
writer.write(sfg.newGroup().append("stringField", "abc").append("createdAt", getNanoTime("2017-05-23 11:59:43.345717").toBinary()));
```